# Is it possible to change account owner on Google Play developers console?

Tags: android, google-play

Account owner is the account who first signed to the developers console and created the app.

Only the account owner can invite people and manage users.

In our case, the person who opened the account is not working with us anymore, and we want to transfer the ownership to someone else in the company.

Is it possible ?

Comment: did you read this? 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en

Comment: @Elior I was trying to avoid opening a new account and paying 25$ again (even if it will be refunded) and move the app to the new account. Just wanted to change the owner for the same account

Comment: The "duplicate" answer show above is not the same as this question.This poster wants to change the owner of the Google Play console (as do I!), the poster of the other question wants to change the owner of an app within the console.

Comment: @Michael .. So you had to create a new developer's account? There is no way to change the owner (Email id) of the existing account?

Comment: @iMDroid Maybe this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52138557/820410

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/

> **The steps to transferring your app/game:**
>
> Visit this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=publishing)
>
> Or click: Developer Home > Help > Contact Support > Developers > Publishing and Distribution Issues
>
> Fill out the form completely and accurately
>
> Select “Transfer Applications to Another Account” from the Issue Type drop down
>   Submit Form
>
> Check your E-Mail and reply with the requested information
>   Forward the E-Mail to the person accepting the app/game transfer and have them reply as requested
>
> Wait for Google to wave their magic wand

Comment: it seems that to only change the email of the owner you'd have to go through the whole transfer process as well

Comment: But this doesn't even answer the question. Of course you can transfer an app but wasn't the question to change the owner of the developer account?

Comment: I have a developer account and I can't purchase a new one. Is it possible to change the ownership of Developer Account from one email account to another email address (not the case of app transferring from one account to another account)?

Comment: BIt old but it's a top hit on Google. You can't change the account owner without transferring the app. You have to transfer the app to a new account, with a new new owner.

Comment: @VinilChandran Maybe this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52138557/820410

Comment: @MathijsSegers ^

Comment: Thanks for tagging me for a three year old comment :-)

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer to this question is: Absolutely NO.

Google explicity declares:

> **The account owner's email address and country can't be changed.** However, you can use a different email address (username) to identify your Google Account. You can also create a new account using a different email address or country and transfer your apps to your new account.

Source: [Manage your developer account information](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en#zippy=%2Caccount-owner-email-address-and-country)

Comment: The reasonable follow-up is, WHY?

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

There's a form and explanation just for transferring applications between accounts: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213

The actual transfer form is [here](https://play.google.com/console/developers/app-transfer) but I guess can change (e.g. android->google->market->play->store) and the explanation is really important to understand the process.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.