# Google Play Console Developers Account - Transfer ownership

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

As the title mentions - How can I change the ownership of a Google Play Console Developer's Account?

*Change the ownership* means to associate the developer's account with a different Gmail account & let the previous association be let go off (and possibly not pay the $25 USD registration fee again).

**Note**: There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16561707/820410) asked but I think it's *incorrectly* marked as a duplicate of a question which doesn't answer the question. (It answers *How to transfer apps to another account)*.

I also beg to differ that the accepted answer also doesn't seem to answer the question.

Hence, asking & answering this as a separate question for the future readers.

Comment: ...just in hope that someone from Google read this comment and give us a way of doing this transfer of accounts

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You ***cannot*** change/transfer the ownership of a Google Play Console Developers Account.

Once a developer account is created, the email address used to register is permanently tied to the account.

[From the Official Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626):

> **Account owner email address and country**
>
> The account owner email address and country **can't be changed**. However,
>   you can create a new account using a different email address or
>   country and transfer your apps to your new account.
>
> ***Accounts with published or unpublished apps***
>
> To transfer apps to a new account, go to our app transfer checklist.
>
> ***Accounts without apps***
>
> If you haven't published any apps using your existing Play Console
>   account, you can create a new account and cancel your existing
>   account.

However, there is a workaround.

1. You can create a new developer account & make the payment for the same.
2. [Transfer your apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en) to the new developer account.
3. Ask google to close the previous account & they will refund the registration fees of the previous account.

References From official Help Docs:

1. [Transfer apps to a different developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en)

> **Step 1: Make sure your Google Play Developer accounts are registered &
>   active**
>
> Before our team can transfer apps from your original account to a
>   different account, known as your target account, both Google Play
>   Developer accounts need to be fully registered and active.
>
> **Note**: You need to pay the $25 USD registration fee for both accounts.
>   After the transfer is complete, if you want to close your original
>   account, our team can refund its registration fee.

2. [Protect your developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2543765?hl=en&ref_topic=16285)

> **Use a different account for your developer account**
>
> If your developer account is linked to your personal Google Account,
>   consider creating a new account to use for your developer account.
>   This way, if one account is compromised, the other account can still
>   be secure.
>
> If you’ve already registered, our support team can transfer your apps
>   to a new account. To transfer your apps to a different account,
>   register a new developer account, then prepare and request the
>   transfer with our support team.
>
> **Note**: If you close your old account, we will refund your original $25
>   registration fee.

Answer (score 8):

## 2021 Method

You can change the ownership of your account to another in few steps and it usually takes a few hours to get everything done. Steps that I followed to transfers my account is as follows.

1. Unpublish all apps. `all apps > setup > advance settings`
   [image]
2. Open a support ticket in [google play support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/dev_registration?extra.IssueType=cancel&extra.IssueType=cancel&visit_id=637541381928006520-2702473374&ctx=139626&rd=1).

[image]

3. Wait for them to reply

[image]

4. Create a new developer account and reply them the details of both new and original accounts (account email and transaction ID/Order ID).

[image]

5. Google play support will reply with the transfer confirmation (with the refund).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you have any apps in the old account before closing it? As per the email, they want no apps in the old account. So, did you transfer all of your apps to the new account?

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the ownership of apps, not the ownership of accounts.

Have you considered transferring the ownership of all your apps to the new account instead? It should have the same effect. See [Transfer apps to a different developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en-GB)