# Is there a way to change the package name after I uploaded my apk for closed testing?

Tags: android, developer-console, package-name

I uploaded my apk to the google play console and made a test track and released on this test track. But our client wants have their own developer account and release it on that account. Since the app is alread released with a packagename I was wondering is there a way I change/delete the package name on our account. So we can release on his account?

Comment: You will have to either change the package name and upload it to their account. Another option, I believe Google Support might be able to transfer an app over to another account. Not sure about the process though

Comment: Play Console  - under user permission add their account and assign them as owner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561707/is-it-possible-to-change-account-owner-on-google-play-developers-console